# Error Training Keras Model on Google Colab using TPU runtime

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, google-colaboratory, google-cloud-tpu

I am trying to create and train my CNN model using TPU in Google Colab. I was planning to use it for classifying dogs and cats. The model works using GPU/CPU runtime but I have trouble running it on TPU runtime. Here's the code for creating my model.

I used the flow_from_directory() function to input my dataset, here's the code for it

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    MAIN_DIR,
    target_size = (128,128),
    batch_size = 50,
    class_mode = 'binary'
)
```

```
def create_model():

  model=Sequential()
  model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(128,128,3)))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
  model.add(Dropout(0.25))
  model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
  model.add(Dropout(0.25))
  model.add(Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation='relu'))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
  model.add(Dropout(0.25))
  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(Dense(512,activation='relu'))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())
  model.add(Dropout(0.5))
  model.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax'))
  
  return model
```

Here is the code used to initIate the TPU on google Colab

```
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver('grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR'])
tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(resolver)

# This is the TPU initialization code that has to be at the beginning.
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
print("All devices: ", tf.config.list_logical_devices('TPU'))

strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(resolver)

with strategy.scope():
  model = create_model()
  model.compile(
      optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3, ),
      loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
      metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])


model.fit(
    train_generator, 
    epochs = 5,
    
)
```

But when I run this code, I get greeted with this error:

```
UnavailableError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-1970b3405ba3> in <module>()
     20 model.fit(
     21     train_generator,
---> 22     epochs = 5,
     23 
     24 )

14 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

UnavailableError: 5 root error(s) found.
  (0) Unavailable: {{function_node __inference_train_function_42823}} failed to connect to all addresses
Additional GRPC error information from remote target /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0:
:{"created":"@1598016644.748265484","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"third_party/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":3948,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1598016644.748262999","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"third_party/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":394,"grpc_status":14}]}
     [[{{node MultiDeviceIteratorGetNextFromShard}}]]
     [[RemoteCall]]
     [[IteratorGetNextAsOptional]]
     [[cond_11/switch_pred/_107/_78]]
  (1) Unavailable: {{function_node __inference_train_function_42823}} failed to connect to all addresses
Additional GRPC error information from remote target /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0:
:{"created":"@1598016644.748265484","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"third_party/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":3948,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1598016644.748262999","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"third_party/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":394,"grpc_status":14}]}
     [[{{node MultiDeviceIteratorGetNextFromShard}}]]
     [[RemoteCall]]
     [[IteratorGetNextAsOptional]]
     [[cond_12/switch_pred/_118/_82]]
  (2) Unavailable: {{function_node __inference_train_function_42823}} failed to connect to all addresses
Additional GRPC error information from remote target /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0:
:{"created":"@1598016644.748265484","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"third_party/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":3948,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1598016644.748262999","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"third_party/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":394,"grpc_status":14}]}
     [[{{node MultiDeviceIteratorGetNextFromShard}}]]
     [[RemoteCall]]
     [[IteratorGetNextAsOptional]]
     [[TPUReplicate/_compile/_7955920754087029306/_4/_266]]
  (3) Unavailable: {{function_node __inference_train_function_42823}} failed to connect to all addresses
Additional GRPC error information from remote target /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0:
:{"created":"@1598016644.748265484","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"third_party/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":3948,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1598016644.748262999","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"third_party/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":394,"grpc_status":14}]}
     [[{{node MultiDeviceIteratorGetNextFromShard}}]]
     [[RemoteCall]]
     [[IteratorGetNextAsOptional]]
     [[Shape_7/_104]]
  (4) Unavailable: {{functi ... [truncated]
```

I really have no idea, how can I fix this. Neither do I know what do these errors mean.

Comment: Do you use Firebase functions?

Comment: I am certain that I am not using firebase functions.

Comment: The error `failed to connect to all addresses` means that something blocks the connections, maybe a firewall.

Comment: I am using Google Drive to store the pictures used in the Dataset. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Do you try to connect to google colab server `TPUClusterResolver('grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR'])` ?

Comment: Yes, I included that line in my code.

Comment: Do you have an AV installed? Maybe blocks the connection

Comment: What do you mean by AV?

Comment: AV = Antivirus.

Comment: No, I am running the code on Google Colab. The code was ran on the cloud.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220213/discussion-between-marios-nikolaou-and-xethereal).

Comment: Hey,
I want to check if this issue has been resolved?
If not, could you please let us know that what is your MAIN_DIR pointing to?

Comment: It’s just a file directory to the dataset.

Comment: Is MAIN_DIR a local dataset? That will not work on TPUs, since the accelerator runs on a different VM. You'll have to move your dataset to GCS and load it with `tf.data.Dataset` for best results. [This codelab covers the basics](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/keras-flowers-data/#0) and [this document](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/classification-data-conversion) shows how to convert an existing image classification dataset to TFRecords.

Comment: so there's no way to use Colab's TPU without using google cloud?

Comment: You need to have the data on Google Cloud Storage in order to use TPU.

Answer (score 8):

You're hitting a known problem with TPUs - they don't support PyFunction. Details here: [#38762](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38762), [#34346](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34346), [#39099](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39099):

> Sorry for the issue. Dataset.from_generator is expected to not work with TPUs as it uses py_function underneath which is incompatible with Cloud TPU 2VM setup. If you would like to read from large datasets, maybe try to materialize it on disk and use TFRecordDataest instead.

Since `ImageDataGenerator` also uses PyFunction under the hood, it is incompatible with TPUs. Instead, you have to use the tf.data API to load images. [This tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images) explains how to do it.

Comment: Just spent countless hours loading the dataset using from_generator and now I just learned this can't be used with TPU :)